# Generic Method how to

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

so I am trying to make a game and I need this piece of code:

```
GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject);
 obj.SetActive(false);
 pooledObjects.Add(obj);
```

this code is repeated more than one time , so I thought of putting it into a function (AddItem) However, in some cases , I need to use the obj variable and some others not so I need to sometimes return obj and function is as `Gameobject` and some other times I need is as `void` as it doesn't return anything.
I recall learning something called templates in Advance Programming course in C++ After some search I found that It is referenced as Generic functions in C# / Unity

so far I got this :

```
 public T fillList<T>(T param)
 {
     GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject);
     obj.SetActive(false);
     pooledObjects.Add(obj);
    // return obj;
 }
```

now my problem is that return obj is giving me an error , I am very unfamiliar with the syntax and way of writing generic functions , how can I remove the param and return the obj when it is called as `Gameobject`?

Comment: You want to cast `GameObject` to `T`? If so, you can do `return (T)obj;`. You can remove `T param` if you don't use it.

Comment: in case T was nothing , like nothing should be returned would this still work?

Comment: can't convert T to gameobject

Comment: `T` cannot be "nothing"... I misunderstood  you question.

Comment: is there a way to reach my goal ?

Comment: The way to reach your goal is by following the "Separation of Concerns" principle. The function for filling your list of objects should have absolutely nothing to do with returning any object from the list. You should have one function for filling the list, and one (or multiple) for getting an object from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "in some cases , I need to use the obj variable and some others not so I need to sometimes return obj and function is as `Gameobject` and some other times I need is as `void`"

This have nothing to do with generics. Always return the Gameobject from the method. You are not obligated to use it in the calling method.

A code like this is perfectly valid:

```
int DoStuff()
{
    return 5;
}

void ExecuteDoStuff()
{
    var stuff = DoStuff();

    // some more code using stuff (an int value of 5)

    DoStuff(); // don't use the return value of DoStuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks , for some reason I did that and it gave error previously before asking , I redid it now and it worked thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it is always going to be a `GameObject` (or something derived from `GameObject`), you can use a generic constraint, and write your function like this:

```
public T FillList<T>() where T : GameObject
{
    T obj = (T)Instantiate(pooledObject);
    obj.SetActive(false);
    pooledObjects.Add(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

When you call it, you can choose whether or not you are interested in the result.

Comment: If you know it's always going to be a `GameObject`, why use generics?

Comment: I was assuming that the code would contain various objects derived from `GameObject`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It would be better to have `T`  be `UnityEngine.Object` rather than GameObject as GameObject is [`sealed`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sealed-class-in-C-Sharp/). `param` can also be removed, as the parameter isn't being utilized here. You can still have a generic return type, however.

Comment: @Draco18s You're probably right, but I had no idea UnityEngine was even a thing until you mentioned it. I have removed the `param` though.

Comment: @bornfromanegg `GameObject` extends `UnityEngine.Object` (which is different from `System.Object`). All of Unity's resources that can be loaded via `Resources.Load<?>` inherit from `UnityEngine.Object`, so that's the  generic typing makes sense. :) Mind, you can't necessarily *instantiate* all of those (e.g. `Component`) but it's "good enough".